# Monsters weak to oil? What oil?

Tags: magicka-square-tablet

I'm playing the newly released Magicka: Wizards of the Square Tablet for the iOS and have read that the Seagul is the only creature weak to Oil.  Oil?  I haven't seen any oil in the game?  How do I use oil?  I can only assume this is a as-yet undiscovered spell combo but I haven't been able to find anything on this.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you maybe mean [Grease](http://magicka.gamepedia.com/Grease)?

Comment: Nope, the description says specifically that the Seagul is "the only monster weak to oil"

Comment: Considering that it's magicka and the developers have a very quirky sense of humor, it might just be a reference to sea birds dying in oil spilling accidents, not a reference to real game mechanics.

Answer (score 3):

There is a robe called the 'Contaminated Robe' that says 'Spells inflict Oil status instead of Wet status'.  This is the only other reference I've found to 'Oil' so far.

Comment: Also scourge has a chance of inflicting oil.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are two ways of getting oil: using the contaminated robe with water and the oil rain spell. Earth, water, water, earth, or water surrounding the earth.

Comment: Where is the oil rain spellbook found?

Comment: @badp Unlocked by: Completing the level The Fallen Maiden, located at the End of the World in The Underworld. Must be unlocked to cast.